# Convergence and uniform convergence of an infinite integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R^+$.  Consider the integral
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^a|\sin x|^b}\,\mathrm dx.$$

We want to find out when does the integral converge and whether the convergence is uniform.

**My attempts.** My gut tells me that the integral only converges when $a-b>1$ and the convergence should not be uniform. (Since $\sin x$ may look like $x^{-1}$ in my experience. But I don’t know if I am right.)
For the proof, first I found it hard to make an estimation using series expansions. Next I tried estimating the following hoping to apply Cauchy convergence theorem but also failed.

$$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^a|\sin x|^b}\,\mathrm dx.$$

I would be extremely appreciative of any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sin(x)\geq 2x/\pi$ for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ and $|\sin(x)|$ is periodic with period $\pi$ and simmetry $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$. Therefore 
$$\begin{align}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{dx}{1+x^a|\sin x|^b}&\leq
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{1+(k\pi)^a(\sin x)^b}\\
&\leq
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+(Ax)^b}=\frac{2}{A}\int_{0}^{A\pi/2}\frac{dt}{1+t^b}
\end{align}$$
where $A=\frac{2}{\pi}(k\pi)^{a/b}$.

Moreover, if $a>b$ then as $k\to +\infty$, $A\to +\infty$ and
$$\frac{2}{A}\int_{0}^{A\pi/2}\frac{dt}{1+t^b}\leq 
\frac{2}{A}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{1+t^b}+\frac{2}{A}\int_{1}^{A\pi/2}\frac{dt}{t^b}=\frac{C_1}{k^{a/b}}+\frac{C_2}{k^{a}}.$$

It follows that we have uniform convergence at least when $a>b$  and $a>1$.